# nginx index.html on all url

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I would like to do like this

```
localhost/ | index.html
localhost/category | index.html
localhost/notes | index.html
localhost/notes/note1 | index.html
```

And I tried to do this but infinity mistakes stoped me.
When I'm trying to use localhost then I see it.

*Rewrite or internal redirection cycle while processing "/index.html"* - this error 500.

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        root C:/Users/Sergey/Desktop/xxx/angular2do;

        location / {
            if ($request_method = POST) {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            } 

            if ($request_method = GET) {
                rewrite ^.*$ /index.html last;
            }

        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        # error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        # location = /50x.html {
        #    root   html;
        # }

    }
```

I know stack has a lot of questions for this problem but I used to be all of them and always catched error.

Comment: I have one file - index.html and inside it has many addiction. Client code on angular 2.
I used to be break and then there is a mistake too... on side angular 2. Nginx don't give all files which need. I don't now how to do this have you any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `rewrite ... last` inside a `location` block will just cycle around rewriting `/index.html` to `/index.html`. You should use `rewrite ... break` instead. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

If your application also requires resources (css, js, images), you may adopt an alternative approach that returns the static file if it exists, for example:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    root C:/Users/Sergey/Desktop/xxx/angular2do;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @other;
    }
    location @other {
        if ($request_method != POST) { rewrite ^ /index.html last; }
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }
}
```

Comment: I get a mistake `nginx: [emerg] named location "@other" can be on the server level only in C:\nginx-1.11.9/conf/nginx.conf:61`.
With break - nginx works - but one probrem, it don't give all addiction files inside index.html.

Comment: Angular 2 has a lot files and it spread to many folders.
Thank you for your help

Comment: My answer should replace your existing `location /` block, so that both blocks in my answer are at the server level - see updated answer.

Comment: Oh, yes but a mistake on side angular still exist.
If I use this code `location / {
       root C:\Users\Sergey\Desktop\xxx\angular2do
   }`
All works but nginx requested only for mine page "/" - on other page( for example localhost/category) - no. I don't understand why in your suggestion angular showed in console that some files addiction can not get.

Comment: Seems all works. I removed cash and all works. Thank you very match.